# Windows Hard Drive Recover

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, files, ssd

I just installed Ubuntu when i had windows 8.1, I am new to Ubuntu but not Linux. I had a second hard drive with my libraries on it because my operating system is on a 120 gigabyte solid state drive. it has my pics and music/videos, i really cant lose them, is there any way i can get into the files or mount that 500 gigabyte hard drive and keep my files? i prefer not to remove it and move the  plus 400 gigabyte  of files on there. let me know... Thanks!

```
"Unable to access “Closed Disk    Library Partition”
"Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/digitalblueeye/Closed Disk    Library Partition: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/digitalblueeye/Closed Disk    Library Partition"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
"
```

Comment: They are "closed partitions"

Comment: IF your system is dual boot, do the proper shut down in windows(as in windows 8.1, it has the hybrid shutdown. Search for the methods to do proper shutdown). If not then take the drive which is having problem, connect it to the system having window 7, or window 8.,8.1(do proper shutdown) and boot,shutdown. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows 8, Windows doesn't unmount your filesystems before shutting down, because it doesn't really shutdown, but hibernate. They call this "fast boot". For a dual-boot system, you should deactivate this so that filesystems are unmounted when you shutdown Windows. When you do, this filesystem will be marked as "clean" and you'll have no problems mounting it in Ubuntu.

If you no longer have Windows 8 and need to mount the filesystem, you can drop to a terminal and run `sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/sdb2`. If successful, and it should be, then you can mount your filesystem as normal.